# array not cleared when setting it to []

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this situation where I need to store reference of components in array.

when the render method called I clear the array by this code :

```
this.arr = [];
```

and then use `ref` to push the components I need to the array using this code:

```
<span ref={ref => this.arr.push(ref)} />
```

the problem is that in first render the array have all the two components , but in the later renders the array returns all components but with two other `null`s.

**Checkout this example :**

```js
class Test extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 0};
        this.arr = [];
    }

    render()
    {
        this.arr = [];
        return (
            <div>
                <span ref={ref => this.arr.push(ref)}>Span 1/</span>
                <span ref={ref => this.arr.push(ref)}>Span 2</span>
                <br/>
                <b>Array Length = {this.state.value}</b>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>GET LENGTH</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onClick = () =>
    {
        console.log(this.arr);
        this.setState({value: this.arr.length});
    }

}



ReactDOM.render( <Test></Test> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can any one explain why I get this behavior and why the array not cleared after setting it to `[]` , and how could I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `x` in `"ref"={x => ...}` can and will be `null` at first call and then will be the refernce to you component when react calls it the second time, so if you don't want `null`'s in your array you need to guard check `x` for null before storing it

Comment: thanks , yes this seems the source of the problem , but why `x` could be null ?

Comment: have no clue, that's how react does it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below by managing in state

```
class Test extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 0, arr: []};
    }

      pushToRef = (ref) => {
        if(ref != null){
           this.setState(prevState => ({
             arr: [...prevState.arr, ref]
           }));
        }
      }
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <span ref={ref => this.pushToRef(ref)}>Span 1/</span>
                <span ref={ref => this.pushToRef(ref)}>Span 2</span>
                <br/>
                <b>Array Length = {this.state.value}</b>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>GET LENGTH</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onClick = () =>
    {
        console.log(this.state.arr);
        this.setState({value: this.state.arr.length});
    }

}



ReactDOM.render( <Test></Test> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

you can empty the state wherever required except render. Something like below

```
let arr = [];
thi.setState({
   arr: arr
});
```

Comment: thanks for help , but this not the solution I'm looking for. what I wonder is why the array contains extra two `null`s

Comment: You can do null check and then push into array pushToRef = (ref) => {
            if(ref != null){
               this.setState(prevState => ({
                 arr: [...prevState.arr, ref]
               }));
            }
          }

Answer (score 1):

Try

`this.arr.length = 0;`

You are reinitializing the variable to a new empty array instance.

Not too familiar with React but my guess is that the instance of the array that the view is referencing is lost as soon as you set the array equal to a new array instance;

Comment: thank for help , but this not solving the problem , still two extra `null`s logged